# How to dynamically set a template for a material design $mdDialog?

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material, mddialog

I'm using angular material and I have a requirement for setting the template dynamically in a $mdDialog.  I used resolve to download the template from a server, which I was able to do, but I want to set that downloaded template to the $mdDialog template dynamically.  Is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
  $mdDialog.show({
            controller: 'TaskShowController',
           // template: module.template,(not working)
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: event,
            resolve: {
                task: function () {
                    return task;
                },
                module: ['$q', function ($q) {
                    var defer = $q.defer();
                    require([], function () {
                        module = require('source/tasks/task_show');// downloads both controller and template im using webpack
                        angular.module("basic").register(module.controller)

                        defer.resolve(module);
                    });
                    return defer.promise;
                }]

            }
        })
            .then(function (message) {
                //success function
            }, function (cancelmessage) {
                //cancel function
            });
```

Is there any option or setting with dialog.show to set the template with the above code?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I figured it out myself, remove the module requiring code from resolve and keep it up so that we can get the template varaible as string which we can keep it to $mdDialog template property

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, remove the module requiring code from resolve and keep it up so that we can get the template variable as string which we can keep it to $mdDialog template property